# Can't figure out how to expand Beats Per Minute counter functionality in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have written this code, that lets the user hit the mouse button each time he or she feels a heart beat. And subsquently it will calculate the time between first and last click and from that it will calculate your BPM if this pace continues.

What I want to add is, that it will put about 10 BPM-data (clicks) into an array and then after 10 times clicking it will calculate from the 10 BPM-data your average heart rate and it will tell you wether that is healthy or not. I know it sounds simple, but I am new to javascript, and I find it really awesome to learn this language through making such small applications, there is no better way of learning!

If someone can point me into the right direction, that would be great.

***This is what I have so far:***

```
    lastTapSeconds = 0;
    bpm = 0;

    var tapDiv = document.getElementById("tapDiv");

    function bpmCounter() { 

        var tapSeconds = new Date().getTime();

        bpm = ((1 / ((tapSeconds - lastTapSeconds) / 1000)) * 60);
        lastTapSeconds = tapSeconds;            
        tapDiv.innerHTML = '<h1 style="display:inline;">' + 
                            Math.floor(bpm) + 
                           '</h1><img style="height:150px;width:150px;" src="img/heart.png"/>';  
    }

    tapDiv.onmousedown = bpmCounter;
```

Comment: so you want to store the clicks in a array and when 10 has been clicked work out time to see if its heathy?

Comment: You can use javascript shorthand for an array.  `var last10 = [];` You then add to the array by doing `last10.push(bpm);` You check if you have 10 items: `if(last10.length >=10) { //Do calculations with for loop }` and you should have basically what you need.

Comment: Yes that is right. I am not sure if the array is needed though. But it seems logical. So basically, it will put the BPM of 10 clicks in an array and then after those 10 clicks it will get the 10 BPM from the array it will sum it up and divide it by 10 and then it will compare it to 3 static values that indicate whether the BPM-value is healthy.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond why not leave that as an answer?

Comment: I think I know what to do guys, thank you!

Comment: Since it isn't a complete answer.  The OP wants to learn so I wasn't going to solve it completely.  Plus maybe I misunderstood a bit with how they wanted to run the calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I fixed some parts of your code including a way to calculate average on the fly for you.

Check this fiddle to see if that's what you're looking for!

http://jsfiddle.net/q85awqsp/2/

Main thing would be creation of `var beats = []` and then using `beats.push(Math.floor(bpm))` to add the values;

Full JS here:

```
var lastTapSeconds = 0;
var bpm = 0;
var beats = [];
var average = 0;
var count = 0;

var tapDiv = document.getElementById("tapDiv");

$(document).on('click', function() {
    var tapSeconds = new Date().getTime();

    bpm = ((1 / ((tapSeconds - lastTapSeconds) / 1000)) * 60);
    lastTapSeconds = tapSeconds;
    tapDiv.innerHTML = '<h1 style="display:inline;">' + Math.floor(bpm) + '</h1>';
    beats.push(Math.floor(bpm));
    average *= count;
    average += Math.floor(bpm);
    count++;
    average /= count;

    if(beats.length >= 10) {
        alert("Average " + average);
    }
});
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make this code only work when i click within the <div></div> and not the whole page? Because now the clicking applies to the entire windows.

Comment: I solved it ! instead of $(document).on('click', function() I changed it to $(tapDiv).on('click', function()

Comment: Oh. Yes. Sorry. I only did that because it was hard to see where the div was.

Comment: no sorry! Dude I learned so much, thank you for all your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Rxjs Observables is easy:

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs'; 
import { bufferCount, map, pluck, timeInterval } from 'rxjs/operators';

const btn = document.getElementById("btn"); // get button
fromEvent(btn, 'click').pipe(
  timeInterval(), // get interval between clicks in ms
  pluck('interval'), // strips the inverval property
  bufferCount(10,1),  // buffers last 10 values and return a array of them
  map(arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length), // get avarage of the array
  map(ms => Math.round(60000 / ms)), // calculate bpm
).subscribe(bpm => console.log(bpm + ' bpm'));
```

using bufferCount you'll need to click 10 times until the results shows up at the console.
if you want to show the bpm right when you start clicking and then keep getting avarage of last 10 values, replace the bufferCount line with:

```
.scan((acc, curr) => {
    acc.push(curr);

    if (acc.length > 10) {
        acc.shift();
    }
    return acc;
}, []),
```